# ipython installation on Python 3.2 32bit Windows

Tags: ipython, python-3.2

I downloaded ipython 1.x for Python 3.2.5 and copied extracted file to sitepackages folder in C drive. I went to command prompt and changed the directory to locate ipython folder and then issued 'setup.py install' command. The error message showed ImportError: No modules named setupfiles. Suggest a way out of this

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error message? I don't think anything in our code has ever used something called `setupfiles`. Could it be `setuptools`, `setupbase` or `setupext` instead?

Comment: Well it was setuptools I installed pyreadline and some othertools and Ipython was installed

Comment: OK. With IPython 1.x on Windows\, you needed to install [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) before installing IPython. I think we lifted that requirement in later versions. Is there a  reason you're using Python 3.2? That's quite old now, so if it's possible, I'd recommend updating to 3.5 or 3.4.

Comment: Actually I installed Python 3.2 individually so it was required to use every module individually. I am not using Anaconda Distribution right now. I want to ask if I update to Python 3.5 code written in Python 3.2 would run or I should make such changes.

Comment: Most code written with Python 3.2 should run unmodified in 3.5, but it's possible that some changes will be needed.